# Управление терминалом в Java

Tags: java

Есть ли в Java кроссплатформенное средство управления терминалом: задание цвета шрифта, фона, управление курсором и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой фреймворк spring roo, там неплохая консоль. Посмотрите что за библиотеку он использует.

Comment: Неплохая - это как?